# Second monitor won't turn on on Windows Startup

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Legion Y530 Notebook with a Geforce GTX 1060, which has a HDMI output, running Windows 10 and recently I bought a used LG HD monitor (Model 20m37aa-b) to use for work. This Monitor uses a VGA cable, so I had to buy a HDMI-to-VGA Adapter.

My problem is that the LG monitor won't turn on when I turn my notebook on. But I don't think it's a monitor problem because the monitor DOES work when I unplug the HDMI adapter from my notebook and plug it back. But I have to do this every single day, which not only is annoying, but I imagine it can end up damaging the HDMI port in the long run.

I did some tests to try and detect the problem. From what I could see:

- Going to Windows resolution settings, I can see that Windows does NOT detect the second monitor (and the Monitor says no signal was detected either). That is, until I unplug and replug the cable, like I said above;
- Unplugging the VGA cable from the monitor still doesn't give signal, and unplugging the VGA cable from the adapter also doesn't work. Only unplugging the HDMI side of the adapter from the notebook works.
- Putting my notebook to sleep and then turning it on again doesn't change anything. Which means if the monitor was not detected, it keeps disconnected. If I unplugged and replugged it and the signal was detected, it keeps connected;
- Curious enough if I reconnect the HDMI cable so the signal is detected and then restart the notebook, the monitor usually also turns on;
- The problem seems to happen mostly when my notebook is turned off for long periods of time (as in, when I go to sleep). Being honest, when I turn my notebook off and then turn it on in quick succession, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. But when I go to sleep and turn it on in the morning, there's like a 95% chance I'll have to unplug the cable.
- Sometimes, the monitor wont show the "No signal dectected" message and instead will start flickering in a weird way. As if it was off, then for a split second it dectects a signal but then loses it, turning off again. And it keeps doing this every 5-10 seconds until I unplug the cable.

And that's it, I guess. I have no idea what the problem is, can someone help me?

Comment: Is it possible that the problem comes from the HDMI-to-VGA Adapter? Have you tried another one? Or how about if you turn off  the monitor and turn on it several seconds later. Sometimes, when I wake from the pc from sleep, I will need to first turn off the monitor and turn it on again.

Comment: @Seven Unfortunately I don't have another adapter to test... Also, I have to say it's kinda hard to test things because it's not always this happens and I have no idea how exactly to recreate the problem. These last 2 days it seems to be working normaly, so much that I'm even scared of touching the cable. But I might do it later to try your suggestion of turning off the monitor (although I already kinda tried it, but I did in quick succession instead of waiting like, 2 minutes before turning the Monitor on again)

Comment: @Seven Well, today it happened again, and I tried turning off the  monitor like you mentioned, but still didn't work. When turning on, the monitor just sayd "No Signal Detected" and enters rest mode...